# Trying to knit ioslides with knitr::knit('slides.Rmd') does not render properly in html

Tags: r, r-markdown, tidyverse, knitr

I'm trying to knit ioslides made in Rmarkdown in Rstudio.
We've been told to use the knitr package to do so. And this is to be done in a script not in the same directory as the Rmd file.

```
knitr::knit(input = '/project/slides.Rmd',
            output = '/project/slides.html')
```

The above code does produce an html file. But it does not render properly. If I try to open the file in a browser, it produces this
[image]

Whilst I want it top open as slides ready to be presented. I know `rmarkdown::render` produces the correct result, but we are somehow not allowed to use this. I have been trying to find a solution to this problem, and have included a lot of different input options to the knitr function, even trying to go through the code for the `rmarkdown::render` to figure out how that works. But I cannot get the correct result. Does anyone know what's wrong here?

The header of the Rmd file looks like:
[image]

Thanks!

ETA:
The start of the Rmd file - as requested

```
---
title: "Identification of Important Genes in Leukemia Patients"
output: 
  ioslides_presentation:
      widescreen: true
      self_contained: true
author: Emma
--- 

<style>
.forceBreak { -webkit-column-break-after: always; break-after: column; }
</style>

'''{r setup, include = FALSE}
rm(list = ls())
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library("knitr")
'''

## Introduction

- 7129 measurements of gene expressions
- 72 Leukemia patients
- ALL: Acute Lymphoblastic Leukemia
- AML: Acute Myeloid Leukemia
```

*To write code within stackoverflow, I've changed the notation of a code block within Rmd to ''' instead.

Comment: That looks like you opened the `Rmd` file in the browser, not the HTML file?

Comment: Can you post the start of your Rmd file - not as an image, but as code? Include more than just the YAML header. It would also help to know what does work. If you create a new ioSlides presentation and knit the default document, does it work?

Comment: @GregorThomas, I've added the start of the Rmd file.It is the HTML file, I've opened.

We've tried to create a new ioslides presentation, and knitted the default without any changes. It works using the 'knit' button, but the programmatic knitr::knit call still creates an output, which hasn't been rendered correctly.